# Need to get array of images ID attached to post

Tags: attachments

How can I obtain ID of images attached (and not necessarily inserted) to a custom post type ?
I want to pass this argument in order to use this images in soliloquy slider

Comment: Please take the time to read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Use this function [`get_attached_media`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_attached_media)

```
$images = get_attached_media( 'image' );
```

You can also pass as a second parameter the ID of a post.

This function returns and array of Post object, the ID is in the `ID` property.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the array of Image ID by using this function

```
if (!function_exists('get_associated_media')) {

    function get_associated_media($post_id) {
        $attachmentIds = array();
        $media = get_children(array(
            'post_type' => 'attachment',
            'post_parent' => $post_id,
            'post_status' => 'inherit',
            'post_mime_type' => array('image/jpeg', 'image/gif', 'image/png'),
            'numberposts' => -1
        ));

        foreach ($media as $file) {
            $attachmentIds[] = $file->ID;
        }
        $attachmentIds[] = get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id);
        return array_unique($attachmentIds);
    }
}
```

*This code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

The code is tested and fully functional.

**USAGE:** You have to pass the Post ID in this function and you will get the images ids.

---

Reference:

- [get_post_thumbnail_id](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_thumbnail_id)
- [Image formats](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_allowed_mime_types#Default_allowed_mime_types)
- [get_children](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children)